# Q: AutomationId not getting set on Android with Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-test-cloud

I have a suite of UITest for our Xamarin Forms project. All of the AutomationId's are present in the XAML file and work fine on the iOS project. However when running the tests on Android the AutomationId is not there which is causing my tests to fail.

I've doubled checked using REPL and tree to inspect each view for it's Id's

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing the `AutomationId`'s in the `OnCreate` of the `MainActivity` in the Android native project?

After the `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);` :

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.ViewInitialized += (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ViewInitializedEventArgs e) => {
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (e.View.AutomationId)) {
      e.NativeView.ContentDescription = e.View.AutomationId;
   }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I double checked. Did a clean build as well.

Comment: @Mike Does that delegate ever get called?

Comment: Yes, it's getting called. I stepped thru and the `AutomationId` is getting set, but when running an actual test or looking at `tree` in `REPL` the `AutomationId` is not present.

Answer (score 1):

In android app build using Xamarin Forms, the automation id is converted to **cont-desc**. You can use cont-desc for your test.

Answer (score -1):

There is no automationId itself visible in REPL, but only label or id with the value equal to that set on the automationId, so you should just use Marked passing in the value.